# JUnit Mockito rest template Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am new to JUnit and Mockito framework. Here I am trying to mock the rest template and wanted to return an HTTP Status of 200, but still, it returns a null value. Can someone tell me whats is wrong with my implementation and why is it returning a null value, not HttpStatus OK .

```
Class MyDependencies{

   @Autowired
   RestTemplate template;

}


Class ABC extends MyDependencies{

   void verify(){
       try{
          ResponseEntity<Object> response;
          try{
             response= template.postForEntity("localhost:....",obj,obj);         
           }catch(Exception e){
               throws Exception.......
           }

           if(response.getStatusCodeValue()==200) // When reaches here, Exception is thrown 
                                                 // becoz response is null
                 return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
            else
              throw Custom_Exception.....

          }catch(Exception e){    
              throws Exception..... 
          } 
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
Class MyTesting{

    @InjectMocks
    ABC abc;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate template;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        abc=new ABC();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testingIt(){
         when(template.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
         Assertions.asserDoesNotThrow(()->abc.verify());
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of spring-boot and junit you are having ?

Comment: @code_mechanic Junit 5 & Spring 5.2.8

Comment: Have you specified `@ExtendWith` annotation om your test class with `MockitoExtension` class?

Comment: I m not using, I m using MockitoAnnotations.init(this)

Comment: that cannot be copied and also stack overflow cannot be accessed from the system. Its kind of very secured... So i just put up a rough implementation.... I started learning of JUnit 2 days before and so confused with many stuffs...

Comment: When is used extended with annotation, i m getting  Strict stubbing argument mismatch.

Comment: I made your code running and everything worls fine. `abc=new ABC();` is just not needed, since 'initMocks' does this for you. Can't tell what your problem is...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the matchers which we are supplying from test method are not matching the actual function call in the service class, hence the stub is not executed and the response is null.

Try specifying the when stub like this

```
when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), Mockito.<Class<String>>any()))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"status\" : \"ok\"}", HttpStatus.OK));
```

In this case, I have taken the `String` as an entity I am posting through rest template. You may use some other class here.

Service class call for this will look like this

```
ResponseEntity<String> answer = template.postForEntity("/abc/1", entity, String.class);
```

Also, you have `@InjectMocks` on your service class in your test, so you don't need this line

```
abc = new ABC();
```

`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` is already doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

@code_mechanic is right, issue is with the matchers supplied from the test method.

Rather than below in test method:

```
when(template.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
```

Try this, provide url not anyString() :

```
when(template.postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.endsWith("/abc/1"),any(),any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
```

This way it will figure out URL matching stub, it worked for me.